# rewrite access to collection to avoid "double" finding

Tags: c++

I have such code:

```
std::unordered_map<int64_t /*id_ord*/, LimitOrder> futOrders;

auto i = futOrders.find(orderId);
if (i == futOrders.end()) {
    LimitOrder& newOrder = futOrders[orderId];
            // work
} else {
    LimitOrder& futOrder = i->second;
            // another work
}
```

Here I execute "find" twice:
first time: `auto i = futOrders.find(orderId);`
second time: `LimitOrder& newOrder = futOrders[orderId];`

Can i rewrite it somehow to avoid "double find"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform an `emplace`, and check the return value to know whether the item was inserted or not:

```
std::unordered_map<int64_t /*id_ord*/, LimitOrder> futOrders;

auto i = futOrders.emplace(
           std::piecewise_construct, std::tie(orderId), std::make_tuple());
if (i.second) {
    LimitOrder& newOrder = i.first->second;
            // work
} else {
    LimitOrder& futOrder = i.first->second;
            // another work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `size()` to realize if an element was inserted, like this:

```
auto old_size = futOrders.size();
LimitOrder& order = futOrders[orderId];
if (old_size < futOrders.size()) {
    LimitOrder& newOrder = order;
        // work
} else {
    LimitOrder& futOrder = order;
        // another work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a way to "determine if an order is empty", you could do:

```
LimitOrder& anOrder = futOrders[orderId];

if (anOrder.empty())       
{
   // New order, do stuff that only new orders need. 
}
else
{
   // Old order, update it.
}
```

The `empty` method could of course be something like `if (anOrder.name == "")` or `if (anOrder.orderId == 0)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this overload of [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) instead:

`std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );`

Example:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> m { {0, "A"}, {1, "B"}, {2, "C"} };

int orderId = 1;
// attempt to insert with key you have and default constructed value type
auto p = m.insert( std::make_pair(orderId, std::string()) );

if (p.second) {
    // the element was inserted
} else {
    // the element was not inserted
    std::cout << p.first->second;  // will print "B"
}
```

In both cases, `p.first` is the iterator to the element you search for (or just got inserted).

Comment: This has the disadvantage of requiring construction of the mapped type even when it already exists in the map. (An unnecessary and potentially expensive operation.)

Comment: True. I didn't know that the same can be done with `emplace`. +1 to your answer.